# PHP Loops & array_filter

Tags: php

I have the following code which works fine if there is only 1 value in `$array1`, but if there are 2 or more values in `$array1`, it returns an empty array. I need it to match all values from `$array1`.

```
$array1Imploded = implode(", ", $array1);
foreach ($array1 as $m) {
    $m = array_filter($array2, function($var) use ($array1Imploded) { return preg_match("#\b$array1Imploded\b#i", $var); });
}
print_r($m);
```

What am I doing wrong please? I'm guessing it has something to do with the commas and spaces in `$array1Imploded` but I'm not really sure how to work around them.

Comment: You may want to look up what the `array_filter` function does.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are performing a filter operation on `$array2`, but your code doesn't show what `$array2` contains initially.

Comment: `$array2` is defined earlier in the script. It contains a bunch of country names plus some other data relating to those countries.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the following. User input of 1 or more country names goes into `$array1`. `array_filter` returns only the elements of `$array2` which contain the country names in `$array1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed `array_intersect` instead of `array_filter`.

```
foreach ($array1 as $m) {
    $m = array_intersect($array2, $array1);
}
```